# What if a diskgroup runs out of space?

Tags: oracle

For my BD I have a DATAC8 diskgroup that has still have 38 GB usable space, day by day, it has less space... what will happen when it's over? can the BD stop or something?

Comment: In your current situation, if the DG is decreasing every day, it means that you have tablespaces with AUTOEXTEND ON and they are getting storage from the DG. When you run out of space, the database will keep working until you add more space to the DG. if you have applications running against such database, they won't be able to add more data in the tables where your tablespaces have been exhausted. Advise: Try to avoid it and add disks to your ASM asap. However, if the tablespace affected is system or sysaux, then you might have loss of service

Comment: Now I understand everything better! , is an exadata. And yes, the tablespaces are with autoextend on. Free up space with RMAN of obsolete backups, I'll see what else I can do!

Comment: free space of rman oboslete backups will not release space in the DG. Normally you have the flash recovery are in a different disk group

Answer (score -1):

you can be backup your data and you can restart your pc

Comment: And how, exactly, does taking a backup and restarting the DB deal with running out of disk space?